# UIPagviewController subview diappears in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController inside UIViewController. I want to add an UIView to the PageViewController which would contain the Next & Previous buttons for Page Curling.(I know buttons arent required, its just for UI display.)

When in Portrait mode, My UIView (red box) is visble on the UIPageViewController (yellow background)

[image: Landscape Mode]

[image: Portrait Mode]

I have tried [view bringtoFrontview] & [view sendtoback] & [pageController.view insertSubview] but could get it worked...

Appreciate any kind of help..!! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit late to answer this but still.
You might want to set

```
self.subView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight + UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Also you should implement layoutSubviews in your view to be able to reset the frames of any subviews that your subview might have.